# Getting HDBC working on Mac

Tags: macos, haskell, sqlite, cabal

Im trying to understand how to work with SQL databases using Haskell and HDBC on my Mac.

To get HDBC working with Debian I can use the following setup:

```
sudo apt-get install sqlite3
sudo apt-get install libghc-hdbc-sqlite3-dev
cabal install HDBC sqlite HDBC-sqlite3
```

My questions are:
How do I get and install libghc-hdbc-sqlite3-dev on a Mac?
Why do I need libghc-hdbc-sqlite3-dev? 
Why can I not use cabal for libghc-hdbc-sqlite3-dev?
Why do I need both sqlite and HDBC-sqlite3, is not sqlite a dependency for HDBC-sqlite3 and downloaded automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you need to `apt-get install libghc-hdbc-sqlite3-dev`.

Have a look at [this page](http://apt-browse.org/browse/ubuntu/trusty/universe/amd64/libghc-hdbc-sqlite3-dev/2.3.3.0-3build1/) for a manifest of that Debian package. It looks like it just contains a compiled version of the `HDBC-sqlite3` Haskell package, and you are already installing that with your `cabal install ...` command.

Comment: Yes it is strange, the example is taken from the book Learning Haskell Data Analysis. The example works perfectly fine without libghc.. so not sure why the author includes it...